# Does DNS and cover all Ports

Tags: dns

If I buy a DNS namespace, does it cover all my ports? Or only ones I configure it to on their server.
For example, I buy **foo.com**, I can use more than port 80 with that domain space correct?

Like for example `ssh root@foo.com`

Comment: I don't believe you understand what DNS is exactly cause you don't "cover" ports.  You understand a domain (not Dsn) is what foo.com is right?  Furthermore it points to your IP address and you can open any port you want, ssh can be on any port, you want

Comment: even a web browser can do e.g. www.blah.com:8080/   to access port 8080 (and do http/https) rather than port 80 (doing http/https). So you can specify the port in a browser, along with the domain. Some companies use this so they run a private intranet on port 8080. so within the company they can do `http://www.thecompany.com:8080`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

DNS is really a question-and-answer type system.  Using TXT records, essentially anything can be communicated with DNS.  Using an [SRV record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record), a port can be used.

However, the most common uses of DNS are likely for AAAA records (IPv6 addresses), A records (IPv4 addresses), CNAME records ("Canonical names", basically pointers to other names), and MX records ("mail exchange" records, identifying E-Mail servers.)

When you get a DNS name, you can use any DNS record type, and you can have your name point to an IPv6 address and/or an IPv4 address.  Each IP address can be matched with any valid TCP port number (there are 65,536 TCP port numbers) and/or any valid UDP port number (there are 65,536 TCP port numbers).

e.g., one domain name can point to an IP address, and that address can use one port number for standard HTTP (typically TCP port 80), one port number for HTTPS (typically TCP port 443), one port for SMTP (typically TCP port 25), and one port for Submission (typically TCP port 587).  Such behavior is common.

Furthermore, if you have a domain name like example.com, you can control sub-domains, like nameone.example.com and nametwo.example.com and namethree.example.com, and have each sub-domain contain different AAAA and/or A records that point to different IP addresses.

So, yes, you do have quite a bit of flexibility.